# How create string with escape character?

Tags: string, go, escaping

I want to create string `\"str\"` but i want to give variable name to str.
For ex : 

`x := "name"
q := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", x)`

I want q = `"\"name\""`

I tried [this](https://play.golang.org/p/hi10SzmnOp)

Comment: Does `q := fmt.Sprintf("\\\"%s\"\\", x)` work?

Comment: Or use raw string literals: ``(`\"%s\"`)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use escape sequences preceded by `\` to show literal special characters in a formatted string `\\` for `\` and `\"` for `"`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := "hello"
    q := fmt.Sprintf("\\\"%s\"\\", x)
    fmt.Println(q)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more functional, flexible solution, depending on your taste:

```
x := "hello"
p := []byte{'"', '\\', '"', '"'}
q := append(append(p, []byte(x)...), p...)
fmt.Printf("%s", q)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MHOsdefZYW